# Data Encryption in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, php-openssl

I was hoping someone would be able to clarify something for me. I have a class to encrypt data and I also use the code to make it into functions instead of a class. Now they use the same keys and everything but if I encrypt something using the class I cannot decrypt using the function why is this? is it one way more secure than the other?

this is the class

```
class Encryption {

var $secret_key;
var $key;

public function __contruct(){
    $this->secret_key = 'MYSECRETKEY12345654321';
    
    // hash
    $this->key = hash('sha256', $this->secret_key);
    
}

public function encode($value){
    
    $output = openssl_encrypt($value, 'AES-256-CBC', $this->key, 0, substr(hash('sha256', "0ac35e3825857c810f86e384d1ac59e8"), 0, 16));
    $output = base64_encode($output);
    
    return $output;
    
}

public function decode($value){
    
    return openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($value), 'AES-256-CBC', $this->key, 0, substr(hash('sha256', "0ac35e3825857c810f86e384d1ac59e8"), 0, 16));
    
}
```

}

this is the function

```
function encrypt($value)
{
    $secret = 'MYSECRETKEY12345654321';
    $key = hash('sha256', $secret);
    $output = openssl_encrypt($value, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, 0, substr(hash('sha256', "0ac35e3825857c810f86e384d1ac59e8"), 0, 16));
    $output = base64_encode($output);
    return $output;

}

function decrypt($value)
{
    $secret = 'MYSECRETKEY12345654321';
    $key = hash('sha256', $secret);
    return openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($value), 'AES-256-CBC', $key, 0, substr(hash('sha256', "0ac35e3825857c810f86e384d1ac59e8"), 0, 16));

}
```

code example

```
$encrypt = new Encryption();
$private = $encrypt->encode(10);
$public = decrypt($private);//this will return false;
```

Comment: You have a typo. `__contruct` should be `__construct`.

Comment: wow that was it?! thank you for pointing that out. Is one way better than the other?